# What has been your experience with RhoMobile + JqueryMobile + KnockoutJS?

Tags: android, blackberry, ios5, jquery-mobile, rhomobile

My team and I have been engaged in building several cross-platform (BlackBerry, Android, iOS) mobile apps for our organization using RhoMobile + JqueryMobile + KnockoutJS. The development experience is acceptable considering the state of cross-platform mobile application development today. The frustration starts to come when using the application on the mobile devices themselves. Performance issues are the number one pain point for us at this time. I don't want this to be a rant but I would like to know what others have done to alleviate performance problems. Specifically, performance issues on BlackBerry devices. I've tried the [solutions recommended in the RhoMobile docs](http://docs.rhomobile.com/faq). Perhaps there are other hints the community can offer. I appreciate any feedback you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have experience with Jquery mobile, and while I loved the fast paced development it makes possible, if I had the time, I would always code a native app. Jquery mobile apps work best on iOS devices due to Safari's CSS3 support. Animations like slide etc are quite choppy on Android browser and downright shoddy on Blackberry's browser.

Apart from that, Jquery mobile works by basically never switching pages. Every time you request a new page (via a hyperlink or whatever), it fetches the page via an AJAX request and inserts it into the current page's DOM (you can explicitly request this not to happen, but then you cannot 'slide' to another page). This form of navigation causes problems after a long-ish chain of navigations. Not to mention, you have to be very careful no two elements across your entire application share the same id.

I made this Jquery mobile app as a demo for a school project, so it served the purposes I needed: fast development and it served as a proof of concept.

However, for my own company's product, we are developing mobile apps, and I would never go with anything but native apps for that. It does take a lot longer to develop, so it depends on your requirement.

**Addition to your comment:**

Nothing that Jquery Mobile does cannot be done by Jquery alone. But, using jquery, if you add the CSS3 animations, use the single-DOM navigation style etc., you'll suffer the same issues. The problem isn't with Jquery mobile. The problem is, few mobile browsers can handle the effects Jq mobile employs. Like I said, iPhone does good. This is partly because of Safari 3's CSS 3 implementation, and mostly because the iOS prioritizes UI threads above background workers.

Comment: This was in answer to the question in the title (what has your experience been..), not the body (alleviation of performance issues). It was too long to leave as a comment :/

Comment: We have turned off animations for the reason you describe. The ajax remark is a good point as well.

Comment: jQuery Mobile 1.0 Final automatically removes pseudo-pages from the DOM after you navigate away from them (that is if they are pulled in from an external document). This is their form of memory management, however leaks can still occur since all references to any of the removed elements may not also be removed.

Comment: If I remove references to JqueryMobile (JS and CSS), the apps perform very well. What does JqueryMobile give that cannot be achieved with Jquery alone?

Comment: Thank you for that clarification @xbonez. Have you tried any other mobile frameworks such as Sencha? If so, any thoughts about them?

Comment: I spent quite some time looking into Sencha, Rhomobile etc, but I realized the best way was to write native apps. Since our timeframe allows it, I find it the best solution.

Comment: @AmirKhawaja jQuery Mobile mainly gives you nice mobile widgets that allow easy navigation on small screens.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `box-shadow` and `text-shadow` from the CSS, it makes the pages quite a bit slower.
2. You can also set the `-hover` and `-down` classes to be the same as their derivatives so that the browser doesn't have to redraw the page when you tap an element (like a `listview` link) when scrolling (this made scrolling on my Android 2.3 device a lot smoother).

To remove shadows:

```
.ui-shadow,
.ui-btn-up-a,
.ui-btn-hover-a,
.ui-btn-down-a,
.ui-body-b,
.ui-btn-up-b,
.ui-btn-hover-b,
.ui-btn-down-b,
.ui-bar-c,
.ui-body-c,
.ui-btn-up-c,
.ui-btn-hover-c,
.ui-btn-down-c,
.ui-bar-c,
.ui-body-d,
.ui-btn-up-d,
.ui-btn-hover-d,
.ui-btn-down-d,
.ui-bar-d,
.ui-body-e,
.ui-btn-up-e,
.ui-btn-hover-e,
.ui-btn-down-e,
.ui-bar-e,
.ui-overlay-shadow,
.ui-shadow,
.ui-btn-active,
.ui-body-a,
.ui-bar-a {
    text-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```

To make the `-hover` classes the same you will need to change styles like this:

```
.ui-btn-hover-a {
    border: 1px solid       #000 ;
    background:             #444444 ;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:                  #fff ;
    text-shadow: 0  -1px  1px  #000 ;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #666 ), to( #444 )); 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #666 , #444 ); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( #666 , #444 ); 
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( #666 , #444 ); 
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( #666 , #444 ); 
    background-image:         linear-gradient( #666 , #444 );
}
```

To be the same as it's derivative (in this case that would be `.ui-btn-up-a`):

```
.ui-btn-hover-a {
    border: 1px solid       #222 ;
    background:             #333333 ;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:                  #fff ;
    text-shadow: 0  -1px  1px  #000 ;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #555 ), to( #333 )); 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #555 , #333 ); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( #555 , #333 ); 
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( #555 , #333 ); 
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( #555 , #333 ); 
    background-image:         linear-gradient( #555 , #333 );
}
```

You can also do this for the `-down` classes which are triggered when a `tap` event occurs on an element:

```
.ui-btn-down-a {
    border: 1px solid       #222 ;
    background:             #333333 ;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:                  #fff ;
    text-shadow: 0  -1px  1px  #000 ;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #555 ), to( #333 )); 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #555 , #333 ); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( #555 , #333 ); 
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( #555 , #333 ); 
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( #555 , #333 ); 
    background-image:         linear-gradient( #555 , #333 );
}
```

Here is a link to the non-minified version of the jQuery Mobile 1.0 CSS style-sheet: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css

Comment: Thank you @Jasper. This helped a bit but not nearly enough on the BlackBerry.

Comment: @Jasper: if you want to add things to your list, I found that adding elements to selectors inside JQM also helps to some degree. So instead of ":jqmData(some="thing") try switching to "div:jqmData(some="thing")

Comment: also I found that creating enhanced jqm markup "by hand" also speeds things up considerably. I filed a "naked JQM" as feature request on Git - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3006

Comment: @frequent thanks for that tip. I feel as if JQM is doing too much out of the box. My team and I have stripped out JQM out of the app. We are now writing our own CSS and using XUI instead of jQuery. The UI is rather quick once you go bare-bones.